# How to hide table column in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I want to design table into rpt file (crystal report 2011)

Table should be appear on report diplay as follow:

Group1:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
Val      Val      Val      Val
```

Group2:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  
Val      Val      Val
```

Note: above Group1 and group2 can be any number of groups as this is just boune field with procedure field.

on all other groups other then Group1 value , i want to hide the `Column4`.

Can any one suggst, how can i create such a table where last column can be appear for particular one group value only and be hidden for all other group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Group using Group Expert.
2. Drop "Val1" , "Val2", "Val3", "Val4" fields in the Details section
3. Type Column names in Group Header, so that will be repeated in every group
4. Right click on "Val4" and "Column4" and type a Suppress Formula (i.e `Group != "Group1"`)
   be careful on formulas: the rule means "suppress when..." and the field name must be drag-drop into de formula

Comment: I have added - horizaontal and vertical line as it is require to appear table with lines. But, Using your ways, i able to hide the column header and column values but, horizontal lines and vertical lines for that particualr column is still appear. and it is unable to hide using supress conditionally. Please suggest some other way to achieve this,

Comment: Ok another way if you want to work on style, too is using 2 details sections and 2 group headers, one with 3 fields and relative lines, and one with 4 fields. Then use suppress formula on section instead of fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

on `column4` supress formula write as below.

```
if(GroupingLevel(<<group1name>>))=1
then false
else true
```

This will make sure that if it is first group then display else hide.